# SormException unsupported type

Tags: scala, playframework, sorm

I have the following model:

```
package models

import java.net.URL
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Page(url: String) {
  var content: String = new URL(url).getContent().toString
  Logger.info("Content is: " + content)
}

object Page {
  implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Page]
}
```

The database representation code is this:

```
package models

import sorm._

object Db extends Instance(entities = Seq(Entity[Page]()), url="jdbc:h2:mem:test")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Cannot invoke the action
[info] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

A bit lower in the stack trace:

```
[info] Caused by: sorm.core.SormException: Unsupported type: (x$1: String)scala.Unit
[info]  at sorm.mappings.MappingKind$.apply(MappingKind.scala:85) ~[sorm-0.3.19.jar:na]
[info]  at sorm.mappings.Mapping$.apply(Mapping.scala:69) ~[sorm-0.3.19.jar:na]
[info]  at sorm.mappings.Mapping$.apply(Mapping.scala:97) ~[sorm-0.3.19.jar:na]
[info]  at sorm.mappings.EntityMapping$$anonfun$properties$1.apply(EntityMapping.scala:18) ~[sorm-0.3.19.jar:na]
[info]  at sorm.mappings.EntityMapping$$anonfun$properties$1.apply(EntityMapping.scala:18) ~[sorm-0.3.19.jar:na]
```

Therefore, I think there is an issue with Sorm but I can't realise what the problem is.

I'm not sure how Sorm works, but I doubt it doesn't support Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the weird stuff you have in the constructor and you're all good. Model by definition is supposed to be only about data. You have implanted a side-effect of fetching from some URL, which is a mistake from the design standpoint either way.

Comment: So say I want to show the user the content of the page. Where should I fetch the data from the page? In another method in the model or in some action in the controller?

Comment: The controller definitely.

Comment: Ok, (I know I'm moving away from the main point a bit) but shouldn't MVC have most logic in the model?

Comment: Model is just data. That's it. Controller reacts to requests by manipulating and processing that data to render a view and produce a response. Hence everything happens in the controller.